# Finding the BigO for the code given in Python

Tags: python, time-complexity

Given is a function below:

```
def count(n):
    total= 0
    i = 1
    while i < n:
        j = n
        while j > 0:
            total += j 
            j -= 1
        i *= 2
    return total
```

I am confused as to what the Big O for this question would be. I am thinking `O(n*log(n))`. Is that right?

Comment: Why do you think it's O(n*log(n))?

Comment: The inner while loop executes n times, and the outer while loop floor(log_2(n)) times, so overall it's Theta(n log n) as you guessed. (Assuming you are asking about runtime in arithmetic operations as a function of the input n).

Comment: I don't think your outer loop actually adheres to the floor(log_2(n)) rule.  By my observation if n = [5, 10, 20] your outer loop runs [3, 4, 5] times yet the floor(log_2(n)) is [2, 3, 4].  Thus, I would say it is more like O(n*n) time.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question is `O(n*log(n))`

Take a number and try it:

```
def count(n=8):
        total= 0
        i = 1
        while i < 8:   #1,2,4  (log(8) -> log(n) iterations)
            j = 8
            while j > 0:  #8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1 (8 -> n iterations) 
                total += j 
                j -= 1
            i *= 2
        return total
```

Hence, O(n*log(n))